# Having trouble with Sprite look at mouse in XNA for game

Tags: c#, mouse, xna-4.0

I understand that this question has been answered before and I've done my research trust me.
I'll say this now, this is a project for school but what I want to do this for my own learning considering that I will be going in to game programmer.

This might get messy but ill do my best
so for this its started as a basic shoot em up, we have a
game.cs- contains all the textures vectors what not, and the

entity.cs- has already begun spritebatch for player to call a player.draw (spritebatch) in
game.cs

player.cs- contains the shooting of the bullet and the position

bullet.cs

enemy.cs

So my problem is that I have the code for updating the sprite to look at the mouse then I would use

```
player.Draw(
            playerTexture,
            position,
            null,
            Color.White,
            rotation,
            spriteOrigin,
            1.0f,SpriteEffects.None,0f);
```

In game.cs draw function, but when I do this I get another sprite (same sprite as my player sprite) that does look at my mouse but I want my other one to look at mouse

But my proff. Wrote the code so that there is an already begun spritebatch in entity.cs

```
public CEntity(CGame myGame, Texture2D myTexture)
    {
        game = myGame;
        texture = myTexture;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the player.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="begunSpriteBatch">Give this function a already begun SpriteBatch.</param>
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch begunSpriteBatch)
    {
        begunSpriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);

    }
```

So in game.cs draw function player.draw is called to draw the player, what can I do to get that look at mouse effect for that sprite?

```
public CPlayer(CGame game, Texture2D playerTexture)
        : base(game, playerTexture)
    {
        texture = playerTexture;
        brotation = rotation;



        position.X = 400f;
        position.Y = 400f;
    }
```

And also player is inherited from entity.

Code for updating the mouse as requested

```
 IsMouseVisible = true;

        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        distance.X = mouse.X - position.X;
        distance.Y = mouse.Y - position.Y;
        //Math.Atan2((double)mouseState.Y - position.Y, (double)mouseState.X - position.X); was using this //before found a different way

        rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(distance.Y, distance.X);

        spriteRectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y,//rotation stuff
            playerTexture.Width, playerTexture.Height);
        spriteOrigin = new Vector2(spriteRectangle.Width / 2, spriteRectangle.Height / 2);
```

Comment: Can you show us "the code for updating the sprite to look at the mouse"?

Comment: Anyone? let me know if i need to add more

Comment: Now I'm not sure I understand the question at all. Right now I'm guessing all you have to do is copy the code that sets `rotation` to another place (or better yet, separate it into a reusable function).

Comment: i actually just figured it out, although im having some trouble with origin i appreciate the help anyway.

Comment: oh and ps indie game devs are awesome i want to be one someday gl with your stick ninja